# Contar Quantidade de Letras em uma String - Delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou criando um programa em que será necessário mostrar a quantidade de letras (A, b, C ..Z; a..z, à,â,ã) presentes em uma String.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
function ContarLetras(Str: String): Integer;
var
    Ret, i: Integer;
begin
  Ret:=0;
  Str:= AnsiUpperCase(Str);
    for i:=1 to length(str) do
    if Str[i] in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] then
       begin
       Inc(Ret);
       ContarLetras:=Ret;
       end;
end;
```

Porém ao executar o programa é exibido um número que não tem nada a ver com a contagem (ex.: 79649600).

Onde será que pode estar o erro?

Comment: Essencialmente tem que fazer na mão, ainda mais sendo um exercício de algoritmo.

Comment: Qual variável esta ficando com esse valor no final?

Comment: É a variável ContarLetras. Uso uma função igual para calcular números de 0 à 9 e dá certo, mas com letras não calcula.

Answer (score 1):

Existem muitas variáveis desnecessárias no seu código, quando você declara uma `function` é obrigado determinar o tipo de retorno (no seu caso é `Integer`). O `Delphi` automaticamente cria uma variável no escopo da `function` chamada `Result` e o seu tipo é o mesmo que o de retorno. Então você só precisa dessa variável e mais uma para fazer o incremento no `for`.

**AnsiUpperCase:**

Essa função faz com que todos os caracteres seja substituídos pela sua versão em maiúsculo. Quando você faz `Str[1]` é retornado um `Char` e a comparação entre `Char` é key sensitive, ou seja, vai diferenciar maiúscula e minúscula.

**Inc:**

Esse função soma e atribui o novo valor a variável passada, quando não se passa o segundo parâmetro que é o número que será somado, ela assume que esse número é 1. Eu tenho uma certa cisma com essa função já tive problemas com ela, mas quando resolvo utiliza-lá faço questão de passar o segundo parâmetro mesmo que ele seja 1, para evitar problemas.

Segue abaixo um exemplo que funcionou bem:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

function ContarLetras(Str: String): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i:=1 to length(str) do
    if Str[i] in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] then
      Inc(Result);
end;

begin
  Writeln(IntToStr(ContarLetras('aa11')));
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Realmente, fui enxugando aqui a função e ficou parecida com a sua. O único problema é ela não contar caractéres com acento.

Comment: Para contar os caracteres com acento você terá que adiciona-los no `array` também. Isso tem que ser feito porque `a` é diferente de `á` e vice-versa.

Comment: Muito obrigado Roberto Campos e a todos que contribuiram.

Comment: Se essa foi a resposta que ajudou a resolver o problema, marque-a como solução da pergunta.

Comment: Pode também resumir o in da seguinte forma: `if Str[i] in ['a'..'z'] then` e para os acentos é só ir adicionando separados com vírgula, exemplo: `['a'..'z', 'á', 'à', 'ã'........]`

Comment: Seguindo o mesmo exemplo da @Melissa você pode colocar um 'A' no começo e um 'z' no final para aceitar tanto caracteres maiúsculos quanto minúsculos. Ficaria assim `if Str[i] in ['A'..'z'] then`. Vale ressaltar que essa forma aceita os caracteres [ ] ^ \ _ e a crase, pois na tabela ASCII eles estão entre o código 65 (o "A" maiúsculo) e o 122 (o "z" minúsculo). Outra alternativa é `if Str[i] in ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'] then`.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver seu problemas com os caracteres especiais, você pode declarar a unit "System.Character" e alterar sua função para:

```
function ContarLetras(Str: String): integer;
var
  umChar: char;
begin
  result := 0;
  for umChar in Str do
    if IsLetter(umChar) then
      Inc(result);
end;
```

Comment: Explicando a função:
forin > faz o loop, já adicionando o char da string em uma variável.
isLetter > função do delphi que verifica se o char é uma letra (maiúscula, minúscula, com acento ou não).

Answer (score 0):

Bom, duas coisas que acho que não estão certas (1) é você converter para maiúscula e comparar com caracteres minúsculos, e (2) o retorno deve ser setado fora do loop.

Como não trabalho com Delphi há anos, não tenho como testar, mas vê se é isso:

```
function ContarLetras(Str: String): Integer;
var
    Ret, i: Integer;
begin
  Ret:=0;
  Str:= AnsiUpperCase(Str);
  for i:=1 to length(str) do
  begin
    if Str[i] in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] then
    begin
      Inc(Ret);
    end;
  end;
  ContarLetras:=Ret;
end;
```

Comment: Valeu Marcos, consegui ver o erro. Realmente não faz sentido comparar maiúsculas com minúsculas.

Answer (score -1):

function ContarLetras(Str: String): Integer;
var
Ret, i: Integer;
begin
Ret:=0;
Str:= AnsiUpperCase(Str);
for i:=1 to length(str) do
if not (Str[i] in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']) then
Inc(Ret);
ContarLetras:=Ret;
end;

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), mas, até lá, escreva apenas respostas que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/381711)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).